# ECMA 2015 syntax is working except for "export" token

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6

I have the following code and it's executed properly. Especially notable are `let`, `const` and `()=>{}`, which, to the best of my understanding, suggest that ECMA 2015 is active and correctly transpiled to the browser.

```
const App = require("./app.js")
const Css = require("./global.sass");
let test = (stuff) => { console.log("this is: " + stuff); }
test("donkey");
```

However, when I add the `export default` statement, the browser tells me that it's an unrecognized token.

```
const App = require("./app.js")
...
export default { }
```

Previously, I've used Babel to transpile and had no problems with the `export` syntax (unless I've done something stupid but then **everything** started to bark at me). At the moment, I'm trying to poke the Angular bear so the loader is *ts*. However, since TypeScript is a superset of ECMA15, that shouldn't affect.

How to troubleshoot this issue? I'm not sure where to start.

Comment: Modules are *not* implemented in browsers yet, despite all the other syntax being supported already.

Comment: @Bergi Aha, so I was tricked to believe that it's my config-magic that made `const` etc. work whereas I could as well do nothing and get that too? Sneaky spot... So I'm still stuck with the Babel, then... Darn. I was so happy to simplify my code and get rid of it...

Comment: You can use babel (or some other module bundlers like rollup) to only transpile modules, and leave the rest of ES6 intact to be executed natively.

Comment: By the way: if you already use babel, and ES2015, require() is not the correct import syntax anymore...

Comment: @MichaelRitter What syntax is valid, would you suggest? *import X from "X";*?

Comment: @AndyJ yes. it would be `import App from './app'` for default exports and `import { Whatever } from './module'` for named imports